# Caching static files isn't working when using nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, caching, nginx, express, proxy

I have an ExpressJS app running behind nginx which I setup as reverse proxy.  I've also setup some caching for static files like images, js and css.  The problem is, they don't seem to actually be caching.  The requests to those files always returns a 200 status code instead of a 304.  If I inspect the headers in dev tools, the Expires header is never the same as it was the last time I requested the file.  It always gets reset to a new value.  Is there something I've missed in my configuration?

I'm using nginx 1.4.4.

Thanks.

```
upstream stats {
  ip_hash;
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
  server_name app.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/stats.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/stats.error.log debug;

  root /srv/www/stats/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://stats;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~* .(ico|css|js|gif|jpg|png)$ {
    expires 7d;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that the expiry time that you see in a header changes with each request because, as the [doc says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html):

> A time in the “Expires” field is computed as a **sum of the current time and time specified in the directive.**

(Emphasis added.) The current time is the time of the request. Since the current time changes with each request, then the expiry time changes too. If what you want is to use the time of last modification of the file instead you'd use `expires modified 7d`.

Now, by setting an expiry date to 7 days into the future, you are telling the browser to not even bother to check again before the expiry. You will get an 304 when the browser checks again, in 7 days. If you want the browser to *always* check when it tries to load the resource again, then set `expires 0`.

Comment: Setting `expires modified 7d` seems to have helped with the Expires header, but I'm still getting a 200 response instead of a 304.

Comment: What process do you use for testing it?

Comment: Just reloading my browser and inspecting the headers in dev tools.  Using expires modified 7d, I did see the Expires header remain to 7 days past the last modified date, even after a page reload.  But status is always 200.

Comment: I also just tested with curl, and I get the same thing.  Always a 200 status.

Comment: I don't believe that `curl` will do it. I've just tested on a server that I *know* I've configured properly and I get 200 no matter what. I believe that `curl` simply does not use a cache. What browser are you using for testing and how do you initiate a reload? It might sound funny to ask but it makes a difference sometimes.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and command+r to reload the page.  I think I may have found my problem though.  I had dev tools open while reloading.  So I checked the settings of dev tools and I had "disable cache while dev tools is open" checked off.  As soon as I unchecked it, I started getting 304 responses...

Comment: That being said, would it be better to not use the "modified" parameter and rely on a version stamp in the file name, which I'm already doing?

Comment: That's one mystery solved, but realize that `Ctrl-r` (I guess `Command-r` is the OS X equivalent?) tells Chrome to *always* check with the server *no matter what the expiry time is*. Even if the file won't expire until 10 years from now, Chrome will check with the server. In normal usage, when landing on your site through a link (not hitting `Ctrl-r`), the browser will not bother to check with the server *until* the expiration time is reached.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)

And yes, Command+R is the OSX equivalent of Ctrl+R on Windows.

Comment: Regarding your last question, when using version in file names, the idea is usually to set `expires` as far in the future as possible (practically, never expire) and cause a reload by changing the file names included in the HTML when a new version is released.